# Vim: spell-check words with diacritics

Tags: accents, vim, spelling

I write my LaTeX documents using Vim with the `vimtex` plugin, and for the most part Vim's spell-checker satisfies my needs. However, I am being quite frustrated by the fact that it does not seem to recognise words with diacritical marks, for example the name

```
Jarn\'{i}k
```

is treated as `Jarn` and `k`. In summary, *is there a way to force Vim's spell-checker to treat a word with diacritical marks as a whole word?*

Comment: If you use `Jarník` (i.e., using utf-8 encoding in your files), it works for me out-of-the box with `vimtex` (and I suppose any `vim` plugin).

Comment: @Rmano I had thought of this myself, but I kept this as a last resort because entering certain diacritics (e.g. `\v`) from the keyboard is much more convoluted. I guess I should have mentioned it in the question, but that is why I formulated it in terms of LaTeX-style diacritics, so to speak.

Comment: @A.P. Late find (and by chance), Luke Smith demonstrates how special characters (think the level of IPA) may be keyed quickly with vim by special key mapping ([video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPvvOEiiF28), and corresponding [GitHub repository](https://github.com/LukeSmithxyz/vimling)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is to enter the text already encoded as UTF-8 and then to instruct `vim` to accept other than, or additional languages to English for the spell check.

With the following example containing two intentional errors:

```
Kiti didieji miestai: Kaunas, Klaipėda, Šiauliai, Panevėžys.

This is correct, but here is an errror

L'école se situe en face de l'hôtel Bienvennu
```

the default correction by `set spell` is the following

[image]

This may be  changed, e.g. to check *only* for French by `:set spell spelllang=fr`:

[image]

or to check simultaneously for multiple languages.  Altogether with Lithuanian, the command here is `:set spell spelllang=lt,fr,en`. Note the list is without a blank after the comma:

[image]

This is how to add new dictionaries to the checker:  As an example, for  Spanish,  call `set spell  spelllang=es`.  This opens a dialogue to fetch the corresponding `.spl` with `wget` to be stored in the path of `.vim/spell`.  There are languages with multiple definitions, e.g. British English / US English.

Comment: I had thought of this myself, but I kept this as a last resort because entering certain diacritics (e.g. `\v`) from the keyboard is much more convoluted.

Comment: @A.P. On Linux, even with a US keyboard, you can enable the Compose key and enter, e.g., Č as Compose-<-C, or put a caron over an arbitrary character with compose-<-space.

Comment: @A.P. I agree with you entering printable special characters require more work, and there may be situations where the more explicit form is the safer one. Yet if the text stays within the Latin script and if coworkers (e.g. IT admin) and OS offer me the liberty, I choose the _US international_ keyboard layout. With muscle memory, this [example](https://dry.sailingissues.com/us-international-keyboard-layout.html) works in Debian (US intl. with dead keys for a 105 key ANSI keyboard) and Windows, too. E.g., in Czech labs, this may be already available next to one of the two Czech layouts, too.